# Is it possible to log down error statements in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, configuration

So that I can just check the logs to see which statements are wrong at a unified location.

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the documentation for the MySQL [error log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html)?

Comment: The error log does NOT log SQL statements that results in errors, does it?

Answer (score 1):

If by "which statements are wrong" you mean "which queries", I don't think the error log helps: it logs mysql starting, stopping, crashing, checking or repairing tables... I think you need to use the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) and post-process it yourself (with a script or something) to extract errant queries only.